# How I can read after EOF? C#

Tags: c#, file, eof

I`m using C# and I need to read something after EOF. Is it possible by using C#? How?
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to be more specific, since EOF usually indicates "things are done here".

Comment: What you need to read 'something' after EOF?

Comment: EOF = END OF FILE, what do u wanna read after that ?

Comment: What do you expect to find after `EOF`? That's like looking for more jam in an empty jar.

Comment: You could potentially check for the EOF THEN do something else.

Comment: Just for my own knowledge, there could in theory be a custom encoding system that would use a different character to indicate the end-of-file (and thus use the EOF character to represent a valid symbol). Can't we read/write such files from/to disk in .NET?

Comment: @dotNET, In modern OS EOF is NOT a special character at all. It's condition, that is true if there is really no any more data can be retrieved from stream(i.e. current position = stream length). Yes there is been special EOF character in MS-DOS(used for tape-based media - to separate different files in the continuing data stream), but it's currently not used anywhere in Windows.

Comment: Given today's cluster sizes this is a good and valid question. It can be translated into: 1 - How can I find out the last disk cluster of my file and 2 - how can I read that disk cluster (low level and completely) ?  The downvoters may want to reconsider their votes..

Answer (score 1):

You cant. `EOF` means end of file, there's nothing actually *in* the file after that.

You may as well ask how you can get ten gallons of oil from a four-gallon drum. Once it's empty, there's no more to be had.

---

Since you're talking C# hence Windows (and based on your comment `and data located behind the end of file pointer`), it's possible that they may be referring to "DOS mode" text files, which are (or used to be, I haven't investigated recently) terminated by the CTRL-Z character.

From the earliest days of the PC revolution, where CP/M used integral numbers of disk blocks to store a file and only stored the number of disk *blocks* rather than the number of bytes, CTRL-Z was used to indicate end of file if the file wasn't an exact multiple of the disk block size.

If that's the case, it's probably best just to open the file as a binary file, then read up to the first CTRL-Z character (code point 26) - everything beyond that could be considered data beyond EOF if it's truly a text file of that format.

Comment: Let me show the task: "..program should provide the ability to view all files specified directory, and data located behind the end of file pointer." I don`t know what does this "end of file pointer" mean